# How to automatically name a pdf file in python

Tags: python, pdf, merge, filenames

I wrote a code that merges pdfs in a specific folder. Now what I would like to do is to create automatic file names for my merged pdfs. Let's say that the first pdf on the list is named: 'Aaa 1.pdf'. I would like python to automatically save the file only as 'Aaa.pdf'. So every time I merge something using python it should delete the last word of the file name and then save the name without it.
Here's my code:

```
import PyPDF2
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger
import os
path = "/PATH/"
pdf_files = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith('.pdf')]
merger = PdfFileMerger()
for files in pdf_files:
    merger.append(path+files)
if not os.path.exists(path+"merged.pdf"):
    merger.write(path+"merged.pdf")
merger.close()
```

Any ideas how to do it?
Also, what if I would  like the third or fourth file on the list to do the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the name is 'Aaa 1.pdf' you can create the string 'Aaa.pdf' like so:

```
#original_name = 'Aaa 1.pdf'
original_name = pdf_files[0]
original_name_split = original_name.split(' ')
new_name = ''.join(original_name_split[:-1]) + '.pdf'
```

Which you can then use to save your file:

```
if not os.path.exists(path + new_name):
     merger.write(path + new_name)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, what I meant is that I don't want to write any file names in my code. I would like python to choose the first file on the list by itself and save it without the last word as my new name.

Comment: All you have to do is change is how original name is created. You can set it to be the first item in your list. I'll add it to the answer

Comment: thank you so much :) You replied so fast and helped a lot!

Comment: @Wega0 glad to do so, if you feel the answer is sufficient please accept it :)

Comment: I'm totally new to coding and my question might surprise you. I managed to save the file like I wanted - but it doesn't have spaces. My pdf file is named 'To read in a month' and it saved as 'Toreadina'. How can I change this?

Comment: you can change the `''.join()` to `' '.join()`

Comment: Thank you! This is all I wanted.